# Why am I getting keyError on this?

Tags: python, indexing, hashmap, keyerror

The problem is:
Given an array containing 0s and 1s, if you are allowed to replace no more than ‘k’ 0s with 1s, find the length of the longest contiguous subarray having all 1s.

Input: Array=[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], k=2
Output: 6
Explanation: Replace the '0' at index 5 and 8 to have the longest contiguous subarray of 1s having length 6.

```
def length_of_longest_substring(arr, k):
    '''
    Create a hashmap that records the values of 0 and 1, initialize them to 0. Do a sliding 
    window.
    WHILE the frequency of 0 is greater than k, subtract arr[windowStart] from HM and then 
    increment 
    wS.
    Use the max function to record longest substring length. Return that.
    '''

    hm = {'0': '0', '1': '0'}
    (windowStart, longest) = (0, 0)
    for windowEnd in range(len(arr)):
        right = arr[windowEnd]
        hm[right] = hm.get(right, 0) + 1
        while hm["0"] > k:
            hm[arr[windowStart]] -= 1
            windowStart += 1
        longest = max(longest, windowEnd - windowStart + 1)
    return longest


def main():
    print(length_of_longest_substring([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 2)) 
    #Return 6
    print(length_of_longest_substring([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 3))
    #Return 9
main()
```

I am getting error with "while hm["0"] > k:" it says

```
File "main.py", line 12, in length_of_longest_substring
    while hm["0"] > k:
KeyError: 0
```

It works if I replace both starting indices with 0.
I tried the .get function aswell. I did hm.get("0"), same error.
I want the while loop to count the VALUES of 0. How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance, all is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing integer and STR convert the STR to int

**Note:** I am not solving the problem but resolving the error as requested by the question.

```
def length_of_longest_substring(arr, k):
    '''
    Create a hashmap that records the values of 0 and 1, initialize them to 0. Do a sliding 
    window.
    WHILE the frequency of 0 is greater than k, subtract arr[windowStart] from HM and then 
    increment 
    wS.
    Use the max function to record longest substring length. Return that.
    '''

    hm = {'0': '0', '1': '0'}
    (windowStart, longest) = (0, 0)
    for windowEnd in range(len(arr)):
        right = arr[windowEnd]
        hm[right] = hm.get(right, 0) + 1
        while (((int)(hm["0"])) > k):
            hm[arr[windowStart]] -= 1
            windowStart += 1
        longest = max(longest, windowEnd - windowStart + 1)
    return longest


def main():
    print(length_of_longest_substring([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 2)) 
    #Return 6
    print(length_of_longest_substring([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 3))
    #Return 9
main()
```

Comment: Your integer conversion looks like it comes from a different language.  And it shouldn't be necessary anyway.

Comment: @MarkRansom I just wanted to make sure that the value from the dict is treated first before the casting can be done

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It returns the wrong answer.

Comment: @Julefikar I wasn't solving the problem for you but resolving the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the logic wrong in your `for` loop. I have modified it and the error got fixed.

```py
# While the frequency of 0 is greater than k, subtract arr[windowStart] from hm and then increment windowStart.
if hm[0] > k:
    hm[arr[windowStart]] -= 1
    windowStart += 1

# Record longest substring length.
longest = max(longest, windowEnd - windowStart + 1)

# Increment the frequency of arr[windowEnd] in hm.
hm[arr[windowEnd]] += 1
```

---

Output:

```
6
10
```

Comment: It gives the same keyError. You need a while loop, not an if statement. My logic is correct, it just ONLY works with any array that starts with a 0.

Comment: In your code, if you typecast `hm[0]` with int (`int(hm[0])`), it shows no errors but outputs `11 13` which is the wrong answer